# Mikortik - заблокировать teamviewer

Tags: iptables, teamviewer

Начну с того, что вариант удалить/запретить на ПК не подходит т.к.:

1. пользователей много
2. есть вероятность, что притащат свой ПК/ноут
3. есть qs версия которую найдут как запустить
4. настройка ПК не под моей ответственностью в принципе.

На данный момент придумал такой вариант:

1. Отслеживать соединения на `tcp:5938`
2. `src-address` добавляется в список(tv-user) на 30 секунд
3. Соединение на `tcp:5938` блокируется
4. для пользователей из списка `tv-user` запрещаются соединения на `tcp:80,443`

В итоге, tv входит в цикл из постоянных переподключений, у пользователя перестают открываться web-сайты, он в истерике звонит в it отдел. Вроде-бы все счастливы, но мне такое решение не нравится т.к.:

1. Доступ к интернет-ресурсам блокируется на время, а такого быть не должно
2. В настройках tv можно указать proxy, но тут уж ничего не поделаешь.

Блокировка производится на `mikritik`, но вариантам с голым `iptables` тоже буду рад, т.к. различия минимальны. Все решения что нашел в сети(обычно предлагают заблокировать доменные имена *.teamviewer.* *.dyndns.* и пр) не работают, так что прошу на них не ссылаться.

Вообще интересует решение на основе анализа трафика, самостоятельно не нашел закономерностей, но может кто еще заморочился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас под рукой микротика нет, проверить не могу, но раньше использовал такие правила:

```
/ip firewall layer7-protocol
add name=teamviewer regexp="^(post|get) /d(out|in).aspx\?.*client=dyngate"
add name=teamviewer1 regexp="^\\x17"
add name=ammyy regexp=^.*rl.ammyy.com.*
/ip firewall filter
add action=drop chain=forward layer7-protocol=teamviewer src-address-list=!yadmin
add action=drop chain=forward layer7-protocol=teamviewer1 src-address-list=!yadmin
add action=drop chain=forward layer7-protocol=ammyy src-address-list=!yadmin
add action=drop chain=forward dst-port=5938 protocol=tcp src-address-list=!yadmin
add action=drop chain=forward dst-port=5939 protocol=tcp src-address-list=!yadmin
add action=drop chain=forward dst-port=5938 protocol=udp src-address-list=!yadmin
add action=drop chain=forward dst-port=5939 protocol=udp src-address-list=!yadmin
add action=drop chain=forward content="teamviewer.com" src-address-list=!yadmin
```

Адреса кому можно пользоваться TV в списке `yadmin`. Заодно и Ammyy Admin блокировался.

Comment: Спасибо. Похоже на то что работает, буду тестировать.